# Pad block corrupted when trying decrypt more that 1 block

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I use BouncyCastle LightWeight Api for AES Encryption because of restricting of key length. I use PaddedBufferedBlockCipher. Here is a simple example of encyption-decryption

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.*;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String text="It's only a simpIt's only a simp";
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
    byte[] key = "16ByteKeyString.".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    cipher.init(true,new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key),"InitializatiVect".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
    byte[] data=text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    byte[] ctext=new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
    cipher.processBytes(data,0,data.length,ctext,0);
    cipher.doFinal(ctext,0);
    System.out.write(Hex.encode(ctext));
    cipher.reset();
    cipher.init(false,new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key),"InitializatiVect".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
    byte[] otext=new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctext.length)];
    cipher.processBytes(ctext,0,ctext.length,otext,0);
    cipher.doFinal(otext,0);
    System.out.write(otext);
}
}
```

When I try to encrypt 1 block, it's all right. But when I encrypt more than 1 block, error occures when decrypting. It's exception "pad block corrupted" in method cipher.doFinal(otext,0);
How can I repair my programm?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made corrections which you pointed out and now my program is working correctly.

Comment: @GregS Please post as an answer, otherwise you (user3791843) could post the code changes and accept your own answer - after a while. Both, please try and close questions, it was not fun reading through all of that for nothing squared.

Answer (score 0):

You're not paying attention to the API. The integer returned by cipher.processBytes(...) is important. The cipher.doFinal() method needs the offset argument to be this value.